# Flux vs Global Variables (in services)

Tags: angular, design-patterns, architecture, flux, ngrx

I am developing flux apps in Angular/NGRX. One intern I am working with said that he used angular services to store data in one of his first applications. At first glance it seemed to me to be incorrect approach, but after a while of consideration I noticed that it isn't much different from the idea of flux store.
What do you think, what are the pros and cons of such approach?
Is it much better to use ngrx store, actions, reducers etc. instead of just plain angular services with some getters/setters?
Thanks!

Comment: Do as you wish, but if you want my opinion, you should use Angular services. This will reduce your bundle since (not using a library), ease the understanding of your code (not everyone knows about ngrx), and might be faster since you use what the framework offers and don't add another one on top of that. But again, this is my two cents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me the difference is a question of convenience and consistency.

You can easily apply most of the redux principles (immutability, pure functions, observable, ...) to an angular service. So you can get many of the same benefits (predictable state mutation, testability, performance, ...) that you would get with a store.

As far as convenience, some of the benefits come easier than others though. For example, it is easy to mimic reducers using the `scan` operator but if you want the memoization you get when creating projections (`createSelector`), then that will probably take a bit more work. If you find that you like dispatching actions (command pattern) then you could create your own event bus. If you find that you like great debug tooling (Redux DevTools chrome plugin) then you would have to write your own integration with it. So you should look at the benefits of the tools already written in ngrx, determine which you actually want, and then decide if it is really worth it to write it yourself.

As far as consistency, in many cases someone else will have to work on "your" code. There is a large benefit to using an industry tested framework. It keeps you from reinventing the wheel (improperly), there is usually good documentation around it (unlike your personal framework), and you can find people in the community who already know it or who can support you when you have issues. So if you find yourself walking down the path of writing anything more than a simple observable service, you might want to take a step back and think about the monster you are creating.

Also Redux isn't just a set of tools, it is a mental framework for solving problems. Having such a framework can bring consistency to the development practices across your team. This is particularly important when there are large skill gaps. In the framework everything has its place so you know where to look for things. Again, you can define this yourself, just gauge the effort to develop, teach, and support.

Additionally, the store is global. Though you could create an observable, monolithic, god service, I expect that isn't your plan (please don't). You are probably creating multiple smaller observable services. There are pros and cons to global so it depends on your situation as to whether you see this as an advantage.

But there is also a cost to using a store. There is a lot of boiler plate (A WHOLE LOT!!!). Also, my main complaint, is that my consumers are abstracted away from my producers (the store is between them). So I can write any rxjs magic where I can manage getting data when it is wanted based on subscription ([ngrx polling to refresh data when subscribed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47597518/ngrx-polling-to-refresh-data-when-subscribed)).

So IMHO, in general if you just need simple observable, shareable data then use a service. If you need more then use a store. It is heavily dependent on your application but I would rather start simple with just a service and move it into the store when I need to. The best advice comes from the react-howto where it says:

> "You’ll know when you need Flux. If you aren’t sure if you need it, you don’t need it."

Further reading: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/